# CodeIgniter 4 File Upload validation

Tags: codeigniter, validation, file-upload, codeigniter-4

I am trying to validate a pdf uploaded file of a user.

```
<form action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="p-2 lg:!px-96 mt-5 md:mt-10">
<div class="grid gap-6 md:grid-cols-1">
    <label class="block text-sm" for="pdf">Upload PDF</label>
    <input name="pdf" class="block w-full mb-5 text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" id="pdf" type="file" accept=".pdf">
</form>

    <?php if (isset(session('errors')['pdf'])) : ?>
        <span class="text-red-400 text-sm"> <?= session('errors')['pdf'] ?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

This should be required and with that, I created this validation rule

```
class FullTimeProgramController extends BaseController{
    public function submitApplication(){
        $rules = [
            'pdf' => 'mime_in[pdf,application/pdf]|max_size[pdf,10000]',
        ];

    $customMessages = [
        'pdf' => [
            'required' => 'The pdf file is required.',
        ],
    ];

if (!$this->validate($rules, $customMessages)) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', $this->validator->getErrors());
}
    }
}
```

That validation works well, but not if I add `required` or `uploaded[pdf]` validation rule. Now, even though I upload a correct PDF file, it has still the `The pdf file is required.` Can someone help me point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: What if you change your `$rules` to `$rules = [ 'pdf' => 'uploaded[pdf]|max_size[pdf,2048]|mime_in[pdf,application/pdf]` and remove `$customMessages`. note that you should avoid using `required` for file validation

Comment: See "Important" in https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html#rules-for-file-uploads